# SharePoint Online full width page

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-online

I am still exploring SharePoint Online creating webparts and deploying through visual studio code using Typescript.

I created a HelloWorld webpart and uploaded it on page. I was able to create package file, upload it on App-Catalog, install it and add to page.

Once it is on page its not taking whole page and in Page Layout section I am not able to see full width option.

As you can see from below screenshot, my webpart is in center of the page whereas What I want is It should be full-width, it should take over whole page.

And in Section layout, full width option is missing.

Can anyone suggest me or give me tip of how to create whole page webpart in SharePoint Online using SPFX.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you already packaged it and upload. you can not do it on the SPO site. You need to edit your manifest.json file. You can add "supportsFullBleed": true to enable full width column for your webpart. And package, upload and install to the catalog again.

The down side of this is there is no way to test your full width webpart in your local workbench. You have to do it on SP online. You can find reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json",
  "id": "34f6d7f2-262f-460a-8b65-152d784127cb",
  "alias": "HelloWorldWebPart",
  "componentType": "WebPart",

  // The "*" signifies that the version should be taken from the package.json
  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,

  // If true, the component can only be installed on sites where Custom Script is allowed.
  // Components that allow authors to embed arbitrary script code should set this to true.
  // https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "supportsFullBleed": true,

  "preconfiguredEntries": [{
    "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", // Other
    "group": { "default": "Other" },
    "title": { "default": "HelloWorld" },
    "description": { "default": "HelloWorld description" },
    "officeFabricIconFontName": "Page",
    "properties": {
      "description": "HelloWorld"
    }
  }]
}
```

Also you can use the Oslo master page that exists by default in SharePoint 2013 and Office 365. To change the master you will need to activate the publishing features if you are using collaboration sites, and you will need to use a custom css to remove the extra margins.

```
.contentwrapper {
margin: 0;
}

#titleAreaBox {
margin: auto 20px!important;
}
```

Comment: I already have set 'supportsFullBleed' property as true but still of no use.

Comment: @salah9 Are you using collaboration sites? if so you need change the master by activate the publishing features. And need some custom CSS to remove the extra margins. Updated in answer.

Comment: I created sub site as publishing site and added same webpart, it worked well.

Comment: For testing in the workbench: you can add a plain `.css` file you import in the startup of your webpart with the following content:
`#workbenchPageContent {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
}`
This will make the page take (almost) the full width of the page for testing. Do make sure you remove the import on publish.

Answer (score 0):

The following tip is on the official document:

At this time, the SharePoint Workbench doesn't support testing web parts in the full-width column layout. Instead, you will have to deploy your web part to a developer tenant, create a communication site, and test your web part there.

If you have completed the above operation, you can see that there is **"supportsFullBleed": true** in the mainfest.json folder. You can add it if you don't have it.

Refer to the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column

Answer (score 0):

You could just recursively fix the paddings and margins of all elements beneath the `workbenchPageContent` (and above your webpart).

(it's a hackish solution, but it seems to work really well)

Calling the following function from inside `componentDidMount` solves everything while in the workbench, and if you use `supportsFullBleed` you won't have any problems when deploying.

```js
function fixWorkbench(elem?: any, depth: number = 0) {
  if (!elem && depth === 0)
    elem = document.getElementById("workbenchPageContent");
  if (!elem || depth > 20) return null;
  elem.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
  elem.style.margin = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
  Array.from(elem.children).map(child => fixWorkbench(child, depth + 1));
}
```